# Azure Traffic Manager Custom Header Settings for Application Gateway with Multiple Sites

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager

I'm facing some issues getting the correct custom header in Traffic Manager to check health for multiple sites behind an Application Gateway. These applications are on a single listener in the Application Gateway.

No matter the header variations I am using, I am still getting the "Degraded" status on health monitoring.

Let's say my applications are as such: **app1.example.com**, **app2.example.com**

1. What would be the correct custom header settings in Traffic Manager? I was thinking such as below.

`host:app1.example.com,host:app2.example.com`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Fixed the monitoring "Degraded" status and it's quite silly. I had to add allow the Traffic Manager health checks in the NSG for the Application Gateway subnet. I still have have to add multiple hosts in the customer header.

Comment: Also, it should be host:app1.example.com,host2:app2.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Morariu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909004/morariu) for your comment. I am converting your comment as an answer to help other community member.

Fixed the monitoring "Degraded" status by add allow the Traffic Manager health checks in the NSG for the Application Gateway subnet.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview

For adding multiple hosts in the customer header

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring